# Where can you find job postings for faculty positions in CS theory?

Tags: soft-question, career

What are the best resources for finding job postings for faculty positions in CS theory?  Is there one website or mailing list in particular that is fairly comprehensive?  I currently have the impression that one has to use a variety of resources to get a comprehensive, worldwide list of job postings.  Is this the case?

This question is related to [how to get a job](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/how-to-get-a-job), though the question I'm asking here is, how do you *find out about* a job?

Comment: One resource is the CCI Jobs page, though I don't know how recently it was updated. http://intractability.princeton.edu/jobs

Comment: Ya, the intractability listing is unfortunately quite out of date...

Comment: I just made this CW.

Answer (score 14):

The [CRA jobs site](http://www.cra.org/ads/) is still the best place, although it's not theory-centric. Given the proliferation of postdocs in theoryCS, I think it would be nice to have a dedicated place for theory job postings.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the CRA site, there is the [ACM jobs site](http://jobs.acm.org) (there is a category for academic jobs) and there are listings in the back pages of CACM. I don't know whether these two ACM listings are necessarily identical. The Chronicle of Higher Ed also has [job listings](http://chronicle.com/jobCategory/Computer-sciences-technology/68/).

I'm not sure of any resources more specific (i.e., theory only). Actually, scratch that, the IACR has a [list of crypto positions](http://www.iacr.org/jobs/).

Answer (score 6):

The [DMANET](http://www.zaik.uni-koeln.de/AFS/publications/dmanet/) mailing list is one of the major resources I use.  It "spreads information on conferences, workshops, seminars etc. relating to discrete mathematics and algorithms."  They also sometimes have job postings for positions at the faculty, postdoc, and grad student levels.

Comment: jamie: don't you also use TheoryNet? or is the overlap too strong?

Comment: I hadn't heard of TheoryNet until now :)

Comment: your bro made a similar post on fb a few months ago. (sorry.)

Answer (score 6):

There is also [cstheory-jobs.org](http://cstheory-jobs.org), which in principle seems like a great clearinghouse for CS Theory jobs, but appears to be underutilized. Job posters, advertise [here](http://cstheory-jobs.org)!

Answer (score 1):

The [center for computational intractability keeps a list](http://intractability.princeton.edu/jobs/) with theory-only positions. There's also a page on the [FPT wiki](http://fpt.wikidot.com/jobs:positions-available-and-people-looking) for positions related specifically to parameterized complexity theory.

(Update: Sorry Aaron, I only noticed later that you posted the same link, and earlier; I'll leave it here for completeness.)