# Canadian CS University Positions?

Tags: soft-question

Does anyone know if there is a centralized source of Canadian positions advertised by universities for computer science? I conjecture that this might exist since there are websites advertising [math jobs for Canada](http://www.math.ca/Employment/), plus websites advertising CS jobs in general ([CRA](http://www.cra.org/ads/), [Higher Ed](http://www.higheredjobs.com/)). Additionally, there exists [at least one such opening currently](http://www.cra.org/ads/ads-view/assistant_professor_the_university_of_manitoba/).

This is a special case of a previously studied problem, where it was [asked on cstheory without the Canadian constraint.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7704/where-can-you-find-job-postings-for-faculty-positions-in-cs-theory)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, any answer to this question will also be an answer to the the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Canadian CS community is seriously under-server and under-organized.  The ACM (in the US) completely overshadows us, and since it (nominally anyways) tries to be international, that leaves little room for Canadians to get organized.  So typical community-driven issues, like aggregating jobs, does not happen.  The community is (now) large enough to be able to sustain such an organization (I know, I belong to the [CMS](http://cms.math.ca), the Canadian Mathematical Society, and it manages just fine, and the sizes involved are in the same ballpark).

I realize that this answer is a bit of a non-answer.  But the (unfortunate!) answer to your question is 'no'.  So rather than just saying that, I figured I would elaborate.

---

Ok, so apparently my Google-fu was not good enough.  I just stumbled upon the [CACS/AIC](http://cacsaic.org/), which is the *Canadian Association of Computer Science*.  But the web site is astonishingly bare bones, with no real sign of the purpose, etc.  So still a 'no', but not quite exactly as I had said.  And [CIPS](http://www.cips.ca/) is different, as it really focused on the IT side of things, not so much on the CS.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I'll probably accept this answer, after I ask a couple of knowledgeable sources outside of cstheory.se.

Comment: Checked with others. Doesn't exist. Thanks!