# Faculty hiring differences between US and UK/Germany

Tags: soft-question, advice-request, career

[This question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/how-to-get-a-job) contains some great answers on how to get a job. I wonder whether there are some significant differences if I will be looking for a position in Europe (in particular, UK and Germany) as opposed to in the US. As a PhD student in the US (who's neither a US nor an EU citizen, if that matters), should I do something differently? Some aspects:

- Is there more/less weight placed in UK/Germany on professional services such as journal/conference reviewing?
- Is there more/less weight placed in UK/Germany on publishing in journals as opposed to conferences?
- Should I try to get to know more professors in UK/Germany through conferences? What about doing an internship or a research visit in UK/Germany?

Other differences are also very welcome.

Comment: Your question is much more suited for http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @cody I would like to hear about CS Theory, so I think it's more suited here. There could be a big difference between fields.

Comment: I also think he should ask this question here not on academia. Question stated very clearly is about cs theory neither physics nor chemistry, ... Their suggestion maybe put the OP in a wrong direction (except that you are sure the process of hiring in other fields is exactly same as cs theory). Furthermore when there is a such specific place to ask this question why should put it in the more general site?

Comment: There definitely are major differences in hiring in different European countries, and there are many countries in Europe, so this question strikes me as too broad. I also share cody's doubts about how well it fits CSTheory. BTW there are theorists active in Academia@SE.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I've restricted to two countries in Europe, so the question is hopefully not too broad now.

Comment: I second @Saeed. If you think this question is not suited here, it would be nice if you could please explain why the linked question (which is about a very similar topic) is suited here.

Comment: In 2010 the kinds of questions the site focused on were quite different, and there was no Academia.SE or CS.SE.  Several questions that I asked then I would now vote to close.

Comment: I agree with others that this would be better on [academia.se]. Questions like this get quite good answers there (I wonder, have you checked it?). This is a soft-question and generally soft-questions are a gray area on cstheory and scrutinized more strictly. As Andras said many questions from early period of cstheory would get closed if they were posted now.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Kaveh and Andras, for elaborating the reasons. I've started a question on Academia [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36454/faculty-hiring-differences-in-theoretical-computer-science-between-us-and-uk-ger). Please close this question if that's appropriate.

Comment: @Maram next time you can ping one of the moderators by flagging your post and we can migrate it for you instead of reposting and closing.